# Последовательно идущие единицы (Яндекс.Контест)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Требуется найти в бинарном векторе самую длинную последовательность единиц и вывести её длину.

Желательно получить решение, работающее за линейное время и при этом проходящее по входному массиву только один раз.

Формат ввода

Первая строка входного файла содержит одно число n, n ≤ 10000. Каждая из следующих n строк содержит ровно одно число — очередной элемент массива.

Формат вывода

Выходной файл должен содержать единственное число — длину самой длинной последовательности единиц во входном массиве.

```js
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
 input: process.stdin
});

let lines = [];
rl.on('line', (line) => {
 lines.push(+line);
}).on('close', () => {
 let maxSequence = 0;
 for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
  let b = lines[i].toString();
  let sequence = 0;
  for (let k = 0; k < b.length; k++) {
   if(b.charAt(k) == '1') {
    sequence++;
    maxSequence = (sequence > maxSequence) ? sequence : maxSequence;
   } else {
    sequence = 0;
   }
  }
 }
 process.stdout.write(maxSequence.toString());
});
```

Не могу понять, почему он валится на 3 тесте? Что там такого приходит?

Рабочий код на Python:

```
import sys

count = sys.stdin.readline().strip()

result = 0
max = 0
for i in range(int(count)):
    el = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
    if el == '1':
        result += 1
    else:
        if max < result:
            max = result
        result = 0

print(max if max > result else result)
```

---

Переосмыслил условие, написал другое решение, и теперь падает на 9 тесте...

```js
const readline = require('readline');
const rl = readline.createInterface({
 input: process.stdin
});

let arr;
rl.on('line', (line) => {
 arr = line;
}).on('close', () => {
 let maxSequence = 0;
 let sequence = 0;
 for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] == 1)  {
   sequence++;
   maxSequence = (sequence > maxSequence) ? sequence : maxSequence;
  } else {
   sequence = 0;
  }
 }
 process.stdout.write(maxSequence.toString());
});
```

Что вообще происходит?

Comment: Если каждая строка содержит одно число - то зачем перебирать её символы? Что будет, если строка содержит число 111?

Comment: @MBo , честно говоря, я совсем запутался... может я условие не так понял...

Answer (score 1):

Вот верный код на Kotlin:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
var s: String?
var m: Int = 0          //  Для максимального значения
var count: Int
var old_m: Int = 0      //  Для предыдущего максимального значения
s = readLine()!!
count = s?.toInt()
while (count > 0){
    s = readLine()!!
    if (s == "1"){
        m++
    }else{
        if(old_m < m){
            old_m = m
        }
        m = 0
    }
    count--
}
if(old_m < m){
    old_m = m
}
println(old_m) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Прочитай условие внимательно

> Первая строка входного файла содержит одно число n, n ≤ 1000

Поэтому начинай цикл не с 0 элемента, а с 1

```
for (let i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по условию, достаточно чего-то вроде этого (в синтаксисе могу ошибаться)

```
let sequence = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    if (lines[i] == "1")  {
        sequence++;
        maxSequence = (sequence > maxSequence) ? sequence : maxSequence;
    } else {
            sequence = 0;
           }
}
```

Comment: тоже упало на 3 тесте... Может с тестом что то не так..? или я...

Answer (score 0):

У Яндекса есть видеоразбор этой задачи.

Я тоже начал считать 1 и 0. Тест валился на 3 проходе. Главная проблема была в непонимании, что есть бинарный вектор в понимании Яндекса и что такое "ровно одно число — очередной элемент массива." Число оно и 0 и 1 и 100011110001 и int и long и все, что угодно.

Так же как и многие, переписал логику и у меня тоже начало валиться на 9 тесте. При этом у меня было все ОК. Я мог подавать в виде числа вообще все, что угодно с 0 и 1 завернутое в строку, а дальше происходило волшебство. Но тест валился на 9 шаге.

Потом я увидел пресловутое видео яндекса, где некий щегол рассказывает, что такое бинарный вектор. Это как все изначально и поняли (а теперь внимание на слова) - массив с цифрами (число и цифра... понимаете, да?...) и рисует этот массив, ну типа такого [0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1].

Теперь вернемся к первой задаче Яндекс контеста. Условия задачи гласят: Это разминочная задача, к которой мы размещаем готовые решения. Она очень простая и нужна для того, чтобы вы могли познакомиться с нашей автоматической системой проверки решений.

Главные тут фразы готовое решение и познакомиться с нашей автоматической системой.

Из решения видно, что в коде прописана тупо логика и всё. И ВСЁ!

И вот дальше этот щегол начинает рассказывать про массив вектора, что там могут быть все 1, все 0 или массив вообще null... Стоп ребятки! В предыдущем ВАШЕМ ПРАВИЛЬНОМ решении, проверки на дурака вообще не было. Тупо логика и всё.

Следующий мой код валился уже на 27 тесте из чего я понял, что их тест жестко брутфорсит абсолютно все входящие значения, пихая в них походу дела все, что только влезет. Тут я психанул и сказал, что всё скормленное или не скормленное тестом под видом входных данных, не равное 1, равно нулю и не шибёт. И о чудо! Тест ОК.

Теперь, понимая логику их автотеста, я не понимаю))) почему они не проверили n на >10000. И чему должен быть равен размер массива в этом случае (0 или 10000)???

Кстати, я скормил автотесту решение без участия массива и оно ОК)))

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int maxDlinna = 0;

        BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int lengthOfVector=0;

        try {
            lengthOfVector = Integer.parseInt(bfr.readLine());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // ops!
        } finally {
            if (lengthOfVector<0) lengthOfVector=0;
            if (lengthOfVector>10000) lengthOfVector=10000;
        }
        
        int countOfONES=0;

        for (int i = 0; i<lengthOfVector;i++) {

            int tempInputValue=0;

            try {
                tempInputValue = Integer.parseInt(bfr.readLine());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // ops!
            } finally {
                if (tempInputValue!=1) tempInputValue=0;
            }
            if (tempInputValue ==1) countOfONES++;
            if (tempInputValue !=1 | i>=(lengthOfVector-1)) {
                if (countOfONES>maxDlinna) maxDlinna = countOfONES;
                countOfONES = 0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(maxDlinna);
    }
}
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: стоит убрать из ответа накал страстей, оставив только полезную для читающих информацию.

Answer (score 0):

Яндекс не очевидно описала ввод элементов.

То есть когда вводится

```
5
1
0
1
0
1
```

То 5 - это количество элементов, которые будут введены позже, и первый элемент в последовательности учитывать не стоит.

А вот дальше нужно найти самое длинное количество повторений единицы подряд.

Я это так сделал:

```
import java.io.*;

public class WooHoo {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int maxCountRepeat = 0;
        int countRepeat = 0;

        int n = Integer.parseInt(r.readLine());
        int currentCount = 0;
        while (currentCount < n) {
            String inputElem = r.readLine();
            currentCount++;
            if (inputElem.equals("1")){
                countRepeat++;
            } else {
                countRepeat = 0;
            }

            if (countRepeat > maxCountRepeat) {
                maxCountRepeat = countRepeat;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(maxCountRepeat);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Первое число во входных данных указывает на то, сколько всего будет чисел в последовательности, а **сама последовательность начинается с элемента с индексом 1**

Пример входных данных, которые могут сломать логику, не учитывающую данный факт:

```
1
1
```

В данном случае ответ должен быть **1**, т.к. первое число 1 указывает на то, сколько будет элементов в массиве, а сам массив выглядит вот так: { 1 }

Добавив skip первой строки, у меня получилось добиться статуса **OK** в Яндекс Контесте

```java
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
        //Skip the first number that tells us how many numbers will be in the file
        scanner.nextLine();

        int currentStreak = 0;
        int maxStreak = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            int number = scanner.nextInt();
            if (number == 1) {
                currentStreak += 1;
                maxStreak = Math.max(maxStreak, currentStreak);
            } else {
                currentStreak = 0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(maxStreak);
```

Answer (score 0):

Правильный ответ на Node.js

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
});

let lines = [];
rl.on('line', (line) => {
  lines.push(+line);
}).on('close', () => {
  let result = 0;
  let maxLength = 0;

  for(let i = 1; i<lines.length;i++){
    if (lines[i] == 1) {
      result++;
    } else {
      result = 0;
    }

    if (result > maxLength) {
      maxLength = result;
    }
  }

  process.stdout.write(maxLength.toString());
});
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав "править".

Answer (score -1):

У вас не разобран случай, когда число может состоять из единиц. Также судя по условиям цикл нужно начинать со второй строки. Первая строка - это количество элементов(строк) в массиве.

Вот мое решение:

```js
const readline = require('readline')
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin
})
const lines = []
let counter = 0
let maxcounter = 0
rl.on('line', (line) => {
  lines.push(line)
}).on('close', () => {
  for (let i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
    if (/^[1]+$/.test(lines[i])) {
      counter = lines[i].length + counter
    } else {
      if (maxcounter < counter) {
        maxcounter = counter
      }
      counter = 0
    }
  }
  if (maxcounter < counter) {
    maxcounter = counter
  }
  process.stdout.write(maxcounter.toString())
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    long int num;
    long int cnt = 0;
    long int curr = 0;
    cin >> num;
    int elem;

for (size_t i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
    cin >> elem;
    if (elem == 1) {
        curr += 1;
    } else if (elem == 0) {
        cnt = std::max(curr, cnt);
        curr = 0;
    }
}
cnt = std::max(curr, cnt);
cout << cnt;
return 0;
```

}

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]